# Are you supposed to update permissions on Google play store whenever you add them to your app?

Tags: android, analytics

I know this seems like a stupid question, but I rememeber seeing somewhere about updating permissions or something. Maybe it was only the content rating. So basically my point is do I have to manually update anything in the market.android/publish/Home whenever i add permissions?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

You update your permissions in the AndroidManifest.  If you change these (you will need to do this to access certain APIs), your changes will take place automatically when you upload to the Play Store.